# How to limit OpenAI in langchain to answer questions only from cutom knowledge base provided by me

Tags: chatbot, openai-api, langchain, gpt-3

I am currently working on a chatbot with langchain. I built a chain which can answer questions based on a custom knowledge base (let's say a sitemap) provided by me. But when I asked a quetion ("Who was the sixteenth president of US.") out of the custom knowledge base, it answered the question based on its own general knowledge.

I do not want it to answer the question which are out of the custom knowledge base. Added image of the Jupiter notebook for refrence of my code.